# how to save any callable in c++ template class

Tags: c++, function-object

I wanted to define a scopeguard, which runs some clean up code when scope exit.
And I don't want to use `std::function<void()>` since it has some overhead. Then I come up with this implementation that is templated.

```
template <typename Fn>
class ScopeGuard {
public:
    ScopeGuard(Fn&& fn) : fn_(std::forward<T>(fn)) {}
    ~ScopeGuard() { fn_(); }
private:
    Fn fn_;
};
```

This works nicely for lambdas. However, it does not accept global functions, which are lvalues. How to solve this problem?

I think this is a more general question, how to make a template that can save any callable object (global functions, lambdas, class instance that has `operator()` with **minimal overhead**.

Is the following a better way?

```
template <typename Fn>
class ScopeGuard {
public:
    template <typename T>
    ScopeGuard(T&& fn) : fn_(std::forward<T>(fn)) {}
    ~ScopeGuard() {
        fn_();
    }
private:
    Fn fn_;
};
```

Comment: Does it have to be as generic as `std::function`? If _yes_, then ok, `std::function` is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: Unrelated: Scopeguarding a functor seems wrong. From a resource it's captured or... what? I don't get it.

Comment: _"This works nicely for lambdas"_ ... unless the lambdas are capturing. Then it does not work for lambdas.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why do you think lambdas that are capturing does not work?

Comment: They'll _work_ in the sense that they'll do the _work_ but the carrying functor types are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first implementation works for global functions as well - just use

```
ScopeGuard g(&foo);
```